# Timing issue setting the selected dropdownlist item in document ready handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Backstory:  I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 app and want to provide the customer with two similar pages - a Create and an Edit.
Both pages have two DropDownList selectors which allow the customer to first choose a type of cone or dish and then choose a subtype
based on the first choice (e.g., customer chooses 'waffle cone' and then is presented with the sub-types such as 'chocolate dipped',
'plain', etc.).

I'm keying of of the 'change' event on the `ConeDish` selector to call a Controller action to return the related sub-types.  Something like so:

**View**

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeID, new SelectList(Model.ConeDishTypes, "TypeID", "Name"), "-- Select Cone or Dish --", new { @id = "conedishselector" })
</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubtypeID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- How Big? --", new { @id = "subtypeselector" })
</td>
```

My the document ready handler for the Create page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#conedishselector').change(function () {
            var selectedTypeID = $(this).val();
            if (selectedTypeID != null) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SubtypesForType")', { typeID: selectedTypeID }, function (subtypes) {
                    var subtypesSelect = $('#subtypeselector');
                    subtypesSelect.empty();
                    subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', { value: 0, text: '-- How Big? --' }));
                    $.each(subtypes, function (index, subtype) {
                        subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: subtype.SubtypeID,
                            text: subtype.Name
                        }));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

And I've got a controller action that looks like so:

```
public ActionResult SubtypesForType(int typeID)
{
    using (var db = new IceCreamEntities())
    {
        IEnumerable<Subtypes> subtypes = db.Subtypes.Where(m => m.TypeID == typeID).ToList();
        List<SubtypeIdentifierViewModel> subtypeVMs = new List<SubtypeIdentifierViewModel>();
        foreach (var subtype in subtypes)
        {
            subtypeVMs.Add(new SubtypeIdentifierViewModel(subtype.SubtypeID, subtype.Name, subtype.Size));
        }
        return Json(subtypeVMs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Basically, that just retrieves subtypes which have the matching TypeID passed into the action.
I don't think the view model's structure is germane to the discussion so it is omitted to save space.

Now, this bit for the **Create** seems to work quite well.  There may be ways to improve it (which I'd be glad to hear) but it accomplishes my goal.

But for the **Edit** page, I'm having some difficulty getting the UI to display the previously selected subtype.  My current script code looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#conedishselector').change(function () {
            var selectedTypeID = $(this).val();
            if (selectedTypeID != null) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SubtypesForType")', { typeID: selectedTypeID }, function (subtypes) {
                    var subtypesSelect = $('#subtypeselector');
                    subtypesSelect.empty();
                    subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', { value: 0, text: '-- How Big? --' }));
                    $.each(subtypes, function (index, subtype) {
                        subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: subtype.SubtypeID,
                            text: subtype.Name
                        }));
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $('#conedishselector').trigger("change");

        var theVal = $("#hiddensubtypeid").val();
        $("#debug").val(theVal);
        if (theVal != null && theVal != "") {
            // alert here just to check
            alert("I got here.");
            $('#subtypeselector').val(theVal);
            // I also tried this, but that didn't work without the alert either - didn't think it would though 
            //            $("#subtypeselector option[value=" + val + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Essentially, the `hiddensubtypeid` field on the page holds the previously selected ID for the ice cream being edited here and the script uses that value to set the selector which was populated with the appropriate subtypes as was done in the `Create` page script.

And here I may not be doing this in a "best practices" or even good way (i.e., using that hidden field or calling the change via the trigger inside the document ready handler.) but I wasn't sure how to do this otherwise.

And with all this, the problem I'm having is on which I believe is a timing issue.  This javascript bit will certainly go get the subtypes associated with the cone or dish that was previously specified (this bit isn't shown but the viewmodel passed that in) 
and populate the DropDownList with the selections associated with the selected type but without that debug alert (which I only put in the code because I wasn't certain I was even getting into the conditional) the setting of the subtype doesn't happen.

Admittedly I might be approaching this problem incorrectly and I suspect that my very synchronous brain expects the asynchronous world to work the way my brain looks at this problem, so I'd appreciate any advice on solving this issue and improving my design.  I've left out some of the view and model code mostly because I don't think it is central to the discussion.

---

**A little more info from the "This Feels Hacky" Department:**

If I try utilizing the `setTimeout` to delay things like so:

```
$('#conedishselector').trigger("change");
$(function($) {
    setTimeout(function() {       
        var theVal = $("#hiddensubtypeid").val();
        $("#debug").val(theVal);
        if (theVal != null && theVal != "") {
            // alert here just to check
            alert("I got here.");
            $('#subtypeselector').val(theVal);
        }
    }, 200); // or 500, or 1000
});
```

Things will work but I think this is *at best* a duct-tape solution to the problem.

---

**A Solution:**

So I believe this all comes down to the fact that `getJSON` is an asynchronous call ([Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) and that's clear from the docs since it has a **success callback** which gets executed **at some point in the future** if the request succeeds.  So what's that mean?  It means that barreling through the document ready function, calling `$('#yourfavoriteselector').trigger("change");` and then immediately turning around and expecting the results of `getJSON` to be completed is flawed logic.  Putting the wait, as I did above via the `setTimeout` is a hack and results in a sub-optimal 'solution' to the problem.  It *relies* (poorly, I might add) on the notion that the success callback will have done its thing after waiting 500ms or whatever time specified.

I restructured the function as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#conedishselector').change(function () {
            var selectedTypeID = $(this).val();
            if (selectedTypeID != null) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SubtypesForType")', { typeID: selectedTypeID }, function (subtypes) {
                    var subtypesSelect = $('#subtypeselector');
                    subtypesSelect.empty();
                    subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', { value: 0, text: '-- How Big? --' }));
                    $.each(subtypes, function (index, subtype) {
                        subtypesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: subtype.SubtypeID,
                            text: subtype.Name
                        }));
                    });
                    var theVal = $("#hiddensubtypeid").val();
                    if (theVal != null && theVal != "") {
                       $('#subtypeselector').val(theVal);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('#conedishselector').trigger("change");
    });
</script>
```

and, as Badger suggested, did the selection as part of the success callback, which ensured that the subtypes had been populated.

The upside of doing it this way also is that the user can change the selection of the first DropDownList to some new value (say if she wanted to see what other cones/dishes we offer) and set it back to the original value again.  When that happens, the hidden field still holds the original sub-type that went with the original main type and the the callback code resets the sub-type DropDownList accordingly.  So the user isn't annoyed with having to re-select her dish size or waffle cone type.  That's just a bit of added respect for the user I think, and a nice side-effect of the solution presented.

So this is 'a solution' and perhaps not the best solution, but I wanted to illustrate it for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is indeed timing. You're sending a request for the data and then trying to set the selected item without waiting for the JSON response.

Unless there is a particular reason not to, I'd implement the getJSON success function differently.

On success, when loading the sub types, you could check to see if one of them is your hiddensubtypeid. If it is then select it, if not then leave the default.

If you wanted you could then clear the hiddensubtypeid when it had been "consumed" by the success function although it might make sense in terms of your user experience to always jump to the currently selected item, if the user selects the relevant main type.

Comment: Let me restate what you've written to see if I follow.  So, when I'm iterating through the subtypes, I check if one matches the hiddensubtypeid and then select it, then I clear out the hiddensubtypeid so that subsequent calls to the getJSON (i.e, when the user selects a different main type) it won't select a subtype.  I guess I could key off of the original main type and subtype so that  if the original main type was selected, it could re-select the original subtype.  Is that basically what you're saying?  (Thanks for the response BTW).

Comment: Yes indeed. Or populate the subtypes, then set the selected value (from the hidden value) in the same way as your code tries to at the moment. Either way, handle whether to set the selected value as part of your success function, rather than in the document ready. Cheers